# Hatcher 3.3.21: What is a cone?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to solve exercise 3.3.21 from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and I'm a bit stuck on not quite understanding what he means by *cone* and *cone point*:

> For a space $X$, let $X^{+}$ be the one-point compactification. If the added point, denoted $\infty$, has a neighbourhood in $X^{+}$ that is a cone with $\infty$ the cone point, show that the evident map $H^{n}_c (X;G) \rightarrow H^n (X^{+}, \infty; G)$ is an isomorphism for all $n$. [Question: Does this result hold when $X=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$?]

Okay, so, I would infer from the question that in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$, $\infty$ has no such neighbourhood that is a cone. Thing is though, why not? My naive assumption was that by a cone shaped neighbourhood, Hatcher was simply meaning that there existed some space $Y$ such that if the neighbourhood in question was $N_{\infty}$, then $CY$ is homeomorphic to $N_{\infty}$ and if the homeomorphism is denoted $\phi$ and $p$ is the "tip of the cone", then $\phi(p) = \infty$.

But then it would appear to me that in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ there definitely exists a cone-shaped neighbourhood of $\infty$, specifically, one that is homeomorphic to the cone of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Am I doing something seriously wrong here? If so where? How am I to interpret what Hatcher has written?

Comment: I think the isomorphism still holds. However, the cone over integers is not a neighbourhood as it's not open in $X^+.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, but there does not exist a cone-shaped neighborhood of $\infty$ in the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$.  If you take a subset of the 1-point compactification of the form $A=((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty))\times\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\infty\}$ then there is a continuous bijection $C\mathbb{Z}\to A$ from the cone on $\mathbb{Z}$ (sending the cone over each point of $\mathbb{Z}$ to one of the intervals heading out to $\infty$).  However, there are two issues that prevent this from being a cone-shaped neighborhood.

First, $A$ is not even a neighborhood of $\infty$ in the 1-point compactification.  In the 1-point compactification topology, any neighborhood of $\infty$ must contain a cocompact subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$, which must contain the entirety of $\{n\}\times\mathbb{R}$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  So $A$ does not contain any neighborhood of $\infty$, and indeed every neighborhood of $\infty$ has to contain infinitely many full copies of $\mathbb{R}$ which turn into circles when the point at $\infty$ is added.  (The 1-point compactification can be identified with the notoriously pathological [Hawaiian earring space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).)

Second, even if you were taking a 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}\times[0,\infty)$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$ (so the entire 1-point compactification would really just look like a cone on $\mathbb{Z}$ without any circles), the continuous bijection from $C\mathbb{Z}$ would still not be a homeomorphism.  As above, every neighborhood of $\infty$ in the 1-point compactification would have to completely contain all but finitely many of the edges going out to $\infty$.  On the other hand, the cone topology is a quotient of the product topology on $\mathbb{Z}\times[0,1]$, so a neighborhood of the cone point just has to contain some open interval around the cone point on each of its edges (which can be chosen completely independently of each other).

Comment: This answer looks very promising, but, err-… I’ve never come across the term cocompact before, and googling it I only find definitions in terms of group action, which I’m not seeing here. Can you please just clarify that particular definition?

Comment: Cocompact just means it has compact complement.

Comment: Thanks! Then I think you’ve got it! Just gimme some time to parse it through once more and properly understand it, and I’ll happily grant you the mark for this being the correct answer! :)

Comment: Actually, I just realized what I wrote is not quite correct.  I will correct it in a minute.

Comment: Okay, so, one more question (have patience with me, I’m a slow learner :P): why must a neighbourhood of $\infty$ contain a cocompact subset of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ah! It follows from the definition of the topology in the one-point compactification! (The Wikipedia page on the Alexandroff extension explains it.)